# T4 Template Refresh On Save

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, t4

I have a couple of custom T4 templates that I want to regenerate any time my edmx file (in the same project) changes.

Somehow Entity Framework manages to figure out to refresh the POCO T4 template on save.....but I can't figure out how. At first I thought it had to do with the `<DependentUpon>` tag in the csproj...but that doesn't seem to have any effect except for telling Visual Studio to group one file under another.

How can I get my custom T4 templates to regenerate when my edmx changes, like Entity Framework's POCO tempaltes do?

Comment: You can do it manually using the 'Transform All Templates' button or you can set it up to refresh on build

Comment: I want to do it on save, automatically, not on build or manually.

Comment: You will need to build a visual studio plugin that watches for changes in the edmx files then kicks off the template execution.

Comment: But how does entity framework know WHICH template to refresh?

Comment: Keep in mind, EF has it's own template host. It's only a single template (ok maybe a few templates). The template reads the edmx and generates output. Maybe you should try editing their template and including your template in there. That is a cheap hack but each time your edmx changes your template will run too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this page http://www.olegsych.com/2009/11/t4-toolbox-automatic-template-transformation/ You might be able to create a custom tool to do what you want. A custom tool would be good because you register it on your system and you can set it as the default tool for edmx files. But that requires a bit of work. Using the T4 toolbox looks like it would be a better, quicker option for you.